Why are Arabic words are showing as square boxes (“[] [] []”) in burnt subtitles using FFmpeg?
I first generated the ASS file:
ffmpeg -i foo.srt bar.ass

Which then created this:
[Script Info]
; Script generated by FFmpeg/Lavc60.31.102
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arabic Poetry,16,&Hffffff,&Hffffff,&H0,&H0,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,هذا نص تجريبي باللغة العربية لاستخدامه في العروض.

burning it using:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=bar.ass output.mp4

But the text looks like this [] [] [] [] [] for Arabic words. Why?
Note: “Arabic Poetry” is obviously a font for Arabic texts, so definitely it is isn't the reason.

My immediate guess would be that you are using a font that does not have those glyphs defined. Did you check?

@Zatrapilla actually I am not sure. but the glyphs are probably defined because these are simple arabic words nothing new.

Using ass filter instead of subtitles made it work like a charm:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=bar.ass output.mp4


You may check as self answered coming back here two days later.

I'm glad this worked for you, and thanks for posting your answer.  Do you happen to understand why it worked (your answer was not what I was going to suggest in a comment to try to help out)?  If so, would you mind adding it to your answer?

@AmazonDiesInDarkness ffmpeg magic :) actually it is stated in ffmpeg's wiki: Same as the subtitles filter, except that it doesn’t require libavcodec and libavformat to work https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

Got it.  Thanks for the details and the link to where you found them!
